# Certbot-auto - run via shell script?

Tags: php, python, amazon-web-services, ssl, server

My aim is to create a shell script dynamically on writing just the folder name and i have achieved this now the challenge is to make it secured coming across i got certbot-auto to run which requires certain things to be done when we hit it manually but i need to do it via shell script something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script
/*****MY SITE CREATION SCRIPT*****/

a2ensite $1.work

sleep 2

certbot-auto /*CAN WE DO THIS IN JUST ONE GO*/

echo $1.' site enabled - certbot running'
```

Answer (score 0):

i read $1.work variable and create directory use mkdir commnad

```
mkdir  $1.work   
cd $1.work
```

why you need this certbot also provide a create directory and auto-renew.

**I will suggest referring this   https://certbot.eff.org/all-instructions**

Comment: thanks for your time but i need to install ssl over it, I am done with setting up the directory and etc., just want to know if by any means we can run certbot-auto command without any other interactive means as it asks for parameters to input.

Comment: sudo certbot renew --dry-run 
use this command

please provide what commands you want to run with full details .